# ActionMailer not delivering confirmation emails in test environment - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, capybara

I'm using Rails (4.2.6), Ruby (2.2.4), Devise (4.1.1), Capybara (2.7.1), Capybara-email (2.5.0), Email_spec (2.1.0), Rspec (3.4.0), and Postgres (0.18.4)

After I upgraded the application from Rails 4.1.15 to 4.2.6, several authentification & registration tests fail. Before the upgrade all tests were properly passing.  The code works as expected in the development environment (for example, confirmation emails are sent & viewable in the Rails server terminal).  The problem of non-delivered emails only occurs in the test environment.

Here's the failing rspec ./spec/features/users/authentification_spec.rb:56:

```
#Sign up User

    visit "/"
    click_link "Sign up"

    find(:css, "#user_email").set("tester9@example.com")
    find(:css, "#user_password").set("password900")
    find(:css, "#user_password_confirmation").set("password900")

    expect {
            click_button "Sign up"      
        }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size}.by(1)
```

When a user completes the form and clicks the "Sign up" button, the page redirects to the "About" page and as expected, the following flash message appears: "A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account."
Using save_and_open_page, I confirmed the aforementioned behavior.  However, the spec fails with the following error:

```
Failure/Error:
   expect {
           click_button "Sign up"  
       }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size}.by(1)

   expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/features/users/authentification_spec.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The error indicates that there are no message objects in the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.  The results of Pry confirm that the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array is indeed empty:

```
[1] pry(main)> mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries
=> []
```

Here's the test log when the spec is run:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-09 16:16:25 -0700
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"tester9@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  [1m[35m (0.8ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mUser Exists (3.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'tester9@example.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (1.9ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('tester9@example.com') LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (2.1ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "signup_as", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmation_token",     "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["email", "tester9@example.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a    $04$Vruf8j0A.DdOZLPe0qjVp.4PxzdR7sCdLF4FfyAr4dQSxcQAjpAwy"], ["created_at", "2016-06-09 23:16:25.095386"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-09 23:16:25.095386"],     ["confirmation_token", "EmY8JyaVAxAfiq7oQ98z"], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2016-06-09 23:16:25.097581"]]
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Redirected to http://www.example.com/about
Completed 302 Found in 113ms (ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

The log indicates that a confirmation email was sent, but the deliveries array is empty. Why is that happening?  Is the record not being committed or persisted in the test database for some reason?  I've read related posts about non-delivery of mail, but have not found a solution to my problem.

Relevant code from test.rb:

```
  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.  

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Relevant contents from rails_helper.rb:

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/email/rspec'
require 'email_spec'

  # Includes Devise test helpers (e.g., lets you use Devise's "sign_in" method in tests)

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller 
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
```

Relevant commented-out code from devise.rb:

```
  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
   #config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
```

Mail delivery works as expected in development & production.  What is going wrong in the test environment?  How can I fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Where does the log indicate a mail was sent? It shows a user being saved, doesn't show anything about an email.  Do you happen to be sending the emails with `#deliver_later` (One of the big features of 4.2)?

Comment: Thanks ... you're correct, nothing in the test log indicates an email was actually sent.  I see the email activity only in the development log. No, I'm not using #deliver_later.

Comment: Ok -- is this a JS test?  If so you may need to sleep for a bit after clicking the button to give the action enough time to occur before checking deliveries.size - also can you add the code that's actually sending the mail

Comment: No, it's not a JS test.  However, I did try "sleeping" the test but that didn't solve it.  I'm using Devise's confirmable module. ActiveMail has always handled sending the mail. It worked great before the upgrade in test mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at devise - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/4-1-stable/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L48 - it sends the confirmation email in an after_commit callback -  If you're running with transactional testing enabled the after_commit callback will never be called (because the DB transaction is rolled back and never committed) so the email is never sent.  Disable transaction based testing for that test and it will probably work.

Comment: I'll try that, but how do I "disable transaction based testing for that test?" How do I set that?

Comment: Assuming you're using database_cleaner to control your database strategies for tests (truncation for js tests, etc) you could add a before block into your database cleaner config like - `config.before(:each, truncation: true)  do Database::Cleaner.strategy = :truncation end` and then tag your test with `truncation: true`.  You could also just tag the test `js: true` - but then you'd definitely need sleeps after your button clicks.  If you're not using database_cleaner - how are you controlling your database strategy for different types of test?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Database Cleaner. Tried setting the test with truncation:true, but spec still fails with same error.  Tried setting test with js:true and sleep(0.02), and got error: "Failure/Error: find(:css, "#user_password").set("password900")"

Comment: The sleep is going to need to be longer than that for js: true -- try `sleep 2` to test --  and since that appears to work it means your before block may not be being called -- I can't see your code to tell you why not

Comment: Thank you so much!  These changes fixed the problem: rails_helper.rb:   config.before(:each, truncation: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end   Then calling "truncate true" on the test.  Works as expected now!

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks for the response. I've had this issue for the past couple of days. I added this block `config.before(:each, truncation: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end` to rails_helper and :truncation :true flag to the example block, now tests are passing.

Answer (score 3):

Just to summarize the discussion between Tom Walpole and codeinspired above into a top-level answer for browsers who might not look into comments, their solution (assuming you use DatabaseCleaner) is to make the following modifications:

**rails_helper.rb**

```
# lots of boilerplate and
# other things at the top of this file, but you'll
# eventually see....

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # ... other config stuff ...

  # sometime after this key line, you want to add:
  config.before(:each, truncation: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  # ... other config stuff ...

end
```

For the test that is in question here, you want to modify it to look like the following (note the addition of "truncation: true" in the line starting with the word "it")

**something_spec.rb**

```
# ... other stuff ...
describe "some function" do
  it "performs a function correctly", truncation: true do
    # your test
    # goes here
  end
end
```