# RSpec tests pass in isolation, but fail when run together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

In my `code_controller_spec.rb` my tests pass when I just run the tests in `code_controller_spec.rb`. However, when I run the suite, only the `create`, `edit`, and `update` tests fail within `code_controller_spec.rb`. I'm really not sure where to go from here and I really don't know why my tests fail when running together. I have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` and am using `database_cleaner`. My app works fine locally with the below actions and I don't receive any errors when creating or updating a post. Let me know if you need additional info.

When I run the suite, the failures I get are:

```
1) CodesController admin pages #create posts a new code post
     Failure/Error:
       post :create, params: {
         code: { 
           created_at: Date.today, 
           title: "Code things", 
           content: "The content of the code post",
           user_id: user.id
         }
       }

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :code=>{:created_at=>Fri, 20 Oct 2017, :title=>"Code things", :content=>"The content of the code post", :user_id=>1}, :controller=>"codes"}

2)  CodesController admin pages #edit edits a code post
     Failure/Error: get :edit, params: { id: code }

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"codes", :id=>#<Code id: 1, title: "Code post title", content: "Coding speak that not everyone can understand...", created_at: "2017-10-20 00:00:00", updated_at: "2017-10-21 06:05:27", user_id: 2>}

3) CodesController admin pages #update updates a code post
     Failure/Error: put :update, params: { id: code, code: code2 }

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"update", :code=>{:title=>"Updated title", :content=>"Updated content"}, :controller=>"codes", :id=>#<Code id: 1, title: "Code post title", content: "Coding speak that not everyone can understand...", created_at: "2017-10-20 00:00:00", updated_at: "2017-10-21 06:05:27", user_id: 2>}
```

My `spec/controllers/user/codes_controller_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe User::CodesController, type: :controller do

  let!(:user) { User.create(email: "user@example.com", password: "password") }
  let!(:code) { FactoryGirl.create(:code) }

  before do
    sign_in_as user
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end

  describe "admin pages" do
    render_views

    context "#create" do
      it "posts a new code post" do
        post :create, params: {
          code: { 
            created_at: Date.today, 
            title: "Code things", 
            content: "The content of the code post",
            user_id: user.id
          }
        }
        expect(response).to redirect_to user_codes_path
        expect(flash[:success]).to eq "Post created successfully."
      end
    end

    context "#edit" do
      it "edits a code post" do
        get :edit, params: { id: code }
        expect(response).to render_template :edit
      end
    end

    context "#update" do
      let(:code2) do 
        { title: "Updated title", content: "Updated content" }
      end
      it "updates a code post" do
        put :update, params: { id: code, code: code2 }
        code.reload
        expect(response).to redirect_to user_code_path(code)
        expect(code.title).to eq code2[:title]
        expect(code.content).to eq code2[:content]
        expect(flash[:success]).to eq "Post updated successfully."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My `spec/factories/post_factories.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :code do
    created_at Date.today
    title "Code post title"
    content "Coding speak that not everyone can understand..."

    association :user, factory: :user
  end

  factory :life do
    created_at Date.today
    title "Life post title"
    content "The world moves in mysterious ways; whether we want it to..."

    association :user, factory: :user
  end
end
```

I run `rspec --seed 123 --bisect` and then I run the output of that, but all my tests pass. I should mention I'm very new to `--bisect`.

This is the `rspec --seed 123 --bisect` output and when I run this all my tests pass.

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/user/codes_controller_spec.rb[1:1:1:1,1:1:2:1,1:1:3:1,1:1:4:1,1:1:5:1] ./spec/controllers/user/lives_controller_spec.rb[1:1:1,1:1:2] ./spec/features/admin_create_posts_spec.rb[1:1,1:2,1:3,1:4] ./spec/features/admin_edit_post_spec.rb[1:1,1:2,1:3] ./spec/features/clearance/user_signs_out_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/features/clearance/visitor_resets_password_spec.rb[1:1,1:2,1:3,1:4,1:5,1:6] ./spec/features/clearance/visitor_signs_in_spec.rb[1:1,1:2,1:3,1:4,1:5,1:6,1:7,1:8] ./spec/features/clearance/visitor_signs_up_spec.rb[1:1,1:2,1:3,1:4,1:5,1:6,1:7,1:8] ./spec/features/clearance/visitor_updates_password_spec.rb[1:1,1:2,1:3] ./spec/features/homepage_spec.rb[1:1,1:2] ./spec/features/login_users_spec.rb[1:1,1:2] ./spec/features/logout_user_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/features/showing_all_posts_spec.rb[1:1,1:2] ./spec/helpers/codes_helper_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/helpers/lives_helper_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/helpers/user/codes_helper_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/helpers/user/lives_helper_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/helpers/users_helper_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/helpers/welcome_helper_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/models/code_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/models/life_spec.rb[1:1]
```

My `database_cleaner` config in `rails_helper.rb`

```
require database_cleaner

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.before(:all) do
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.

  config.before(:suite) do
    if config.use_transactional_fixtures?
      raise(<<-MSG)
        Delete line `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` from rails_helper.rb (or set it to false) to prevent uncommitted transactions being used in JavaScript-dependent specs.
                During testing, the app-under-test that the browser driver connects to uses a different database connection to the database connection used by the spec. The app's database connection would not be able to access uncommitted transaction data setup over the spec's database connection.
      MSG
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end  

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    # :rack_test driver's Rack app under test shares database connection
    # with the specs, so continue to use transaction strategy for speed.
    driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test

    if !driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
      # Driver is probably for an external browser with an app under test that does *not*
      # share a database connection with the specs, so use truncation strategy.
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
  end

  # adds this from
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753251/actionmailer-not-delivering-confirmation-emails-in-test-environment-rails-4
  config.before(:each, truncation: true) do 
    Database::Cleaner.strategy = :truncation 
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

UPDATED 
Output for `rails routes`

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
              root GET    /                                       welcome#index
         passwords POST   /passwords(.:format)                    clearance/passwords#create
      new_password GET    /passwords/new(.:format)                clearance/passwords#new
           session POST   /session(.:format)                      clearance/sessions#create
edit_user_password GET    /users/:user_id/password/edit(.:format) clearance/passwords#edit
     user_password PATCH  /users/:user_id/password(.:format)      clearance/passwords#update
                   PUT    /users/:user_id/password(.:format)      clearance/passwords#update
                   POST   /users/:user_id/password(.:format)      clearance/passwords#create
             users POST   /users(.:format)                        clearance/users#create
           sign_in GET    /sign_in(.:format)                      clearance/sessions#new
          sign_out DELETE /sign_out(.:format)                     clearance/sessions#destroy
                   GET    /sign_out(.:format)                     clearance/sessions#destroy
           sign_up GET    /sign_up(.:format)                      clearance/users#new
        user_lives GET    /user/lives(.:format)                   user/lives#index
                   POST   /user/lives(.:format)                   user/lives#create
     new_user_life GET    /user/lives/new(.:format)               user/lives#new
    edit_user_life GET    /user/lives/:id/edit(.:format)          user/lives#edit
         user_life GET    /user/lives/:id(.:format)               user/lives#show
                   PATCH  /user/lives/:id(.:format)               user/lives#update
                   PUT    /user/lives/:id(.:format)               user/lives#update
                   DELETE /user/lives/:id(.:format)               user/lives#destroy
        user_codes GET    /user/codes(.:format)                   user/codes#index
                   POST   /user/codes(.:format)                   user/codes#create
     new_user_code GET    /user/codes/new(.:format)               user/codes#new
    edit_user_code GET    /user/codes/:id/edit(.:format)          user/codes#edit
         user_code GET    /user/codes/:id(.:format)               user/codes#show
                   PATCH  /user/codes/:id(.:format)               user/codes#update
                   PUT    /user/codes/:id(.:format)               user/codes#update
                   DELETE /user/codes/:id(.:format)               user/codes#destroy
             lives GET    /lives(.:format)                        lives#index
              life GET    /lives/:id(.:format)                    lives#show
             codes GET    /codes(.:format)                        codes#index
              code GET    /codes/:id(.:format)                    codes#show
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Rails 5

Comment: @ThomasWalpole specifically 5.1.4

Comment: Rails 5.1+ has builtin DB connection sharing in the test environment, so database_cleaner should not be required in most cases.  Set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` and remove database_cleaner and see if that makes a difference.  If it doesn't fix the issue please post your database_cleaner configuration.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I did what you suggested, but got the same failures. I completely removed the configuration for `database_cleaner` and set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`. Updated the question above.

Comment: Ok -- so the same failures (and the fact that your cleaner config looks fine) probably means you don't need dabase_cleaner at all.  The errors your are getting are weird in that they are about generating URLs, but they work when run separately.  Not really sure how route generation would be affected by other tests being run.  Can you post the output of `rails routes`

Comment: As far as using `--bisect` -- Was the `seed` you're specifying a seed that was returned by a failing run of the tests?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole updated with `rails routes` output.
For `--bisect`, I read a post from Relish app about using `--bisect` and that's the way it said to run it. I'll admit, there's a good chance I may have used it incorrectly as I'm very new to it's implementation.

Comment: But was the seed from a failing run???  You've shown `123` in your question, which probably isn't the actual seed from a failing run, and hopefully you just put that there as a placeholder for the question, and it's not what you actually ran?

Comment: It really seems that your test is trying to create routes for the ::CodesController rather than the User::CodesController, not sure why running other tests first would affect that though.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Same here. I'm really not sure why it's failing like it is. In regards to `--bisect`, I run it and the output is `Bisect started using options: ""
Running suite to find failures... (3.63 seconds)
Starting bisect with 3 failing examples and 52 non-failing examples.
Checking that failure(s) are order-dependent... failure appears to be order-dependent

Round 1: bisecting over non-failing examples 1-52
Bisect failed! 
The example ordering is inconsistent. --bisect relies upon consistent ordering (e.g. by passing --seed if you're using random ordering) to work properly.`

Comment: Yes -- you need to run tests normally - and then use the `seed` reported by a failing run of the test (The `seed` specifies the exact order the tests get run in) to run again using the `--bisect` option -- Then rspec will attempt to figure out (using the seed you passed in to know a failing order) which tests run before the failing test actually cause it to fail.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't receive a message or `--seed` when I run the suite normally.

Comment: then you may not be running in random order -- anyway I think I worked it out - answer added - hopefully that solves it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an autoload issue.  If your `::CodesController` gets loaded before the `Users::CodesController` then your spec for `Users::CodesController` is actually using `::CodesController` and hence can't create the correct routes.  When run singly the correct class is autoloaded and everything works correctly.  To fix this require the correct class at the beginning of your spec.

```
# spec/controllers/user/codes_controller_spec.rb

require 'user/codes_controller'
...
```

and

```
# spec/controllers/codes_controller_spec.rb

require 'codes_controller'
...
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your time and help. I greatly appreciate it.